# Jon Skeet's Edulinq - Empty Array Caching

Tags: c#, caching

I was going through Edulinq by Jon Skeet, and I came across the following code, Page 23, in which he implements cache mechanism for `Empty()` operator of Linq

```
private static class EmptyHolder<T>
{
   internal static readonly T[] Array = new T[0];
}
```

My question is, how does this actually cache the `Array` variable?

Optionally, How does it work in CLR?

Edit: Also following that, he mentions there was a revolt against returning an array. Why should anybody not return an array (even if it is 0 sized?)?

Comment: The value of `Array` is saved for the lifetime of application after `EmptyHolder<T>` is first referenced, due to it being static.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> My question is, how does this actually cache the Array variable?

The CLR caches it per type argument. Basically, `EmptyHolder<int>` is a different type to `EmptyHolder<string>` etc, and the type initializer is invoked (automatically, by the CLR) once per *concrete* type.

So:

```
var x = EmptyHolder<string>.Array; // Needs to construct the empty string[] array
var y = EmptyHolder<string>.Array; // No extra work! x and y have the same value
var z = EmptyHolder<int>.Array; // This constructs an empty array for int[]
```

> Optionally, How does it work in CLR?

That's an implementation detail that I don't know much about, I'm afraid. But basically this is *all* about how the CLR does things :)

> Edit: Also following that, he mentions there was a revolt against returning an array. Why should anybody not return an array (even if it is 0 sized?)?

Well, there was a comment of:

> The array method is not so great: People will incorrectly depend on the return value being an array although this is not documented.

Personally I don't think it's an issue, but it was fun to write the alternative implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you invoke EmptyHolder.Empty() for the firsttime for T, you will have to invoke the static constructor for EmptyHolder.

Now it looks like there is no static constructor, right? Wrong. The class can be rewritten as...

```
private static class EmptyHolder<T>
{
   static EmptyHolder<T>()
   {
       Array = new T[0];
   }
   internal static readonly T[] Array;

   public IEnum<T> Empty();
}
```

Now, subsequent runs of Empty will not invoke the static constructor (unless a different T is used).

Be it as I may to critise Jon Skeet, this is a tiny optimization to be worry about.

Comment: (Sorry for not commenting before this - I haven't seen this question before.) They're not the same. This code has a static constructor; my code doesn't. Both have type initializers, but that's not the same thing. It affects performance a bit, and what sort of guarantee there is of timing. http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx